# How to make a field required in Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Let's say I want to make the firstname field required in sequelize, in mongoose I can just say required: true on that field but how do I do that in Sequelize?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you're using Sequelize, the equivalent of `required: true` on mongoose is just `allowNull: false`. You'd write something along these lines:

```
const YourTable = sequelize.define('your_table', {
  firstname: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,

    // This will require the firstname be present
    allowNull: false,

    // If you want to also have a length restriction, add the next line
    len: [2,50], // only allow values with length between 2 and 50
       // That is 'Al' will be accepted and so will 'Rigoberto Fernando Luis María'. 
       // But '' or 'J' won't be good enough

     // If you use sequelize transforms, this will remove spaces on both ends
     // of the string also
     trim: true,
  },
  // All the other fields (columns)
});
```

---

References:

- [SequelizeJS models definition](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html)
- [Sequelize transforms](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-transforms)

Comment: How I can set, say "[Fieldname] is required?" message for required fields?

Answer (score 7):

To responde to Dmitry question: you can define a custom validation error under the field definition :

```
foo: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
  validate: {
    notNull: { msg: "foo is required" },
  },
}
```

more info [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#model-validations)